# In Emacs, tags-loop-continue doesn't remember whether to be case-sensitive

Tags: emacs, case-sensitive

By default I am happy with case-insensitive search but just now I want to do a case-sensitive search in all the source files I keep listed in the TAGS file.

Natural elisp for this looks like

```lisp
(let ((tags-case-fold-search nil)) (tags-search "Foo"))
```

Indeed eval'ing the above finds the first occurrence of `"Foo"` (not `"foo"` nor `"FOO"`).

But then I want the next occurrence. So I hit `M-,` which runs the `tags-loop-continue` command. Now my search is not case-sensitive anymore :-( It seems that I have to eval `(let ((tags-case-fold-search nil)) (tags-loop-continue))` if I want to continue in case-sensitive mode.

Why doesn't `tags-loop-continue` rely on the value that `tags-case-fold-search` had the last time one ran `tags-search`? Is this something one can obtain easily with the right customization setting?

Comment: Do you get the desired behavior if, after your initial use of `tags-search` with the code provided, you evaluate `(let ((tags-case-fold-search nil)) (tags-loop-continue))`?

Comment: Sure. I modified the question to make this explicit.

Comment: Try setting `tags-case-fold-search` to `nil` globally via `(setq tags-case-fold-search nil)`. How does `tags-loop-continue` behave when you do that? If it behaves the way you want, you can define a custom command that toggles `tags-case-fold-search` and set up a key binding for it. That way, switching from case-sensitive to case-insensitive search (and vice versa) will be as easy as pressing a single key sequence.

Comment: No doubt `tags-search` doesn't *store* the value of `tags-case-fold-search`, but uses it directly. When that command completes, the scope of your let-binding ends, and `tags-loop-continue` is an entirely new command which does not execute within that same scope, so it doesn't see the same value.